# Angular cli universal rendering

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering) to generate universal bundle to my app.

I ended up with:

**dist folder** - the app production files

**dist-server**- the bundle I just created, has `main.js` and `styles.css` in it.

Previously, I was just uploading the dist folder to my web hosting provider directory and could view the app directly.

My question is  - How I can apply the dist-server directory to pre-render my app and actually view the HTML when using "View Source"?